# Simple modulo tester

Tags: javascript, modulo

I have a simple, modulo based script, which runs for 3 and 6 digits to `else`. There are also cases for these numbers, which condition should fit also to these numbers.

```
function caffeineBuzz(n){
    var returnvalue;

    if (n % 3 == 0)
        returnvalue = "Java";
    if (n % 3 == 0 && n % 4 == 0)
        returnvalue = "Coffee";
    if (n % 3 == 0 && n % 2 == 0)
        returnvalue = "Java" + "Script"
    if (n % 4 == 0 && n % 2 == 0)
        returnvalue = "Coffee" + "Script"
    else
        returnvalue = "mocha_missing!"

     return returnvalue;
}
```

`n` stands for input, that is an integer and returnvalue should be a string.

**Update:**
Most specific -> less specific approach helped me, but there are cases, when it returns with wrong value.

```
function caffeineBuzz(n){
    var returnvalue;

    if (n % 4 == 0)
        returnvalue = "Coffee" + "Script"
    else if (n % 3 == 0 && n % 4 == 0)
        returnvalue = "Coffee";
    else if (n % 3 == 0 && n % 2 == 0)
        returnvalue = "Java" + "Script"
    else if (n % 3 == 0)
        returnvalue = "Java";
    else
        returnvalue = "mocha_missing!"

     return returnvalue;
}
```

Comment: Ákos, can you tell us what is the question, what would you want to achieve and how is this function failing?

Comment: *"`if (n % 4 == 0 && n % 2 == 0)`"* - Not what you're asking, but the second part of this condition is redundant.

Comment: You do understand that if `n % 3 == 0`, it will go to `returnValue = "java"` and then will never progress to the other parts, right? So you will *never*  reach the `Coffee`, and `Java Script` parts. If you want the script to be able to reach them, put them up first. Basically, structure the if/else block from most-specific to least-specific. (ie start with `a && b && c && d` before going to less specific parts like `a && b` and ending with `if a`)

Comment: @Tularis - There is only one `return` statement in the function, and no `else if`, so it *will* do the other tests.

Comment: @Tularis: This is the functionality, that I need. But for input 3 it runs into else.

Comment: @LajosArpad : I have updated the question. Tularis's answer is really great, but 3 % 3 = 0, so return should be "Java" in this case.

Comment: Ákos, your question is still unclear for me. It is clear that you want to separate your input into cases, but the cases you want to comply to are completely unspecified, therefore, it is impossible to tell for sure what solutions would comply to your unspecified needs. Can you describe in plain text the thing you want to achieve? If yes, then I will be able to help you. You can describe it in Hungarian as well as long as you do that inside a chat session instead of this comment section.

Comment: Árpád, this code should be similar like FizzBuzz test, just in another aspect. There is a tester which is to test code for predefined values. Code above working for my own values, but maybe there is a semantical error somewhere in it. Input: an integer, output: a string, which comply with rules.

Comment: Ákos, you left us in the dark. I am aware that this is an easy task, but you did not give us the exact specification. I have written an implementation for you, but I do not guarantee it complies to the expectations, since I am not aware of the exact expectations. Since I am unaware of your expectations, I cannot determine wether and where you have problems, I can just guess. I assumed that you have 3 cases.

Comment: The first case is when the number can be divided by four. In this case the string starts with Coffee and continues with Script, if and only if the number cannot be divided by 3. The second case is that the number can be divided by 3 (except the case when it can be divided by four as well, which was discussed in the first case). In this case the String starts with Java and ends with Script, if and only if the number is pair. If the number is not pair and can be not divided by 3, then we have the default text returned: "mocha_missing!". Am I correct in my attempt to decipher your task needs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116676/discussion-between-lajos-arpad-and-kovacs-akos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is the guesstimation of the answer based on comments.

```
function caffeineBuzz(n){
    //Storing n's modulos to not calculate them multiple times
    var mod3 = (n % 3 == 0)
    var mod4 = (n % 4 == 0);
    var mod2 = mod4 || (n % 2 == 0);

    //Maybe: return (mod3 ? ("Java" + (mod4 ? "Coffee" : "")) + (mod2 ? "Script" : "") : "mocha_missing!");
    return (mod3 ? ((mod4 ? "Coffee" : "Java") + (mod2 ? "Script" : "")) : ("mocha_missing!"));
}
```